# the EditText is empty and the method always returns true?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Any idea why this method `isTopicExist()` posted below always returns true;

in the code below, i am checking is the `EditText` has a text or not by calling he method `isTopicExist`, but at run time, i do not enter any text and press the button and i expect to see the `toast` in the `else` statement, but the `toast` never shows and the `if (isTopicExist() && (getSelectedRB() != -1))` is always `true`.

I am missing somethin?

**code**

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isTopicExist() && (getSelectedRB() != -1)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Topic: "+et_topic.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "QoS_Level: "+getSelectedRB());
                subscription_topic = et_topic.getText().toString();
                subscription_QoS = getSelectedRB();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Topic is a mandatory field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        private boolean isTopicExist() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (et_topic.getText().equals(""))
                return false;
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
private boolean isTopicExist() 
{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (et_topic.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                return false;

                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason to ignore case on an empty string?

Comment: i have bee asking about ignoring cases at all :)

Comment: In my particular case I use equalsIgnoreCase() to compare strings and equal to compare two objects for example two classes.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `if` statement as follows:

```
 if (et_topic.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
```

`EditText#getText()` returns an `Editable` object, which won't be equal to `""`.

Comment: is there any built in methd to detect if the field is empty (no chars and no number)? because maybe the user wouldnot leave the edittext empty but he might enter a space and in this case space !0="" and the test will be passed

Comment: The `String#trim()` method will remove any whitespace, if you don't want to count that. I edited my answer to add that, but I would point out that @Ludger had that answer before I did.